How to update a Collection in Livewire Child component after changes in Parent component"
I have the following structure:
A parent component rendering a table (child component).
The parent component is responsible for making a query and passing this query to the child component like this:
@livewire('admin.vendidos.contemplados.table.table-contemplados', ['items' => $items])

Since it comes from the database, items are a collection.
My problem is that the parent component has some filters for this query, and updating any filter changes the query, hence the items change.
This works perfectly, but the issue is that these items are not updated in the child component.
So, how I worked around this problem, but not in the way I would like:
When a filter is modified, the parent component emits an event, where I pass the items as a parameter, and then, I listen to this event in the child component and update the items. Okay, but when I pass the items through an event, they stop being a collection and become an array, so I can access the attributes normally, but I can't access the collection functions.
I know there is the method "collect($items)", but this transforms items into a generic collection, not the original model, meaning I can't access the functions I need.
Note: I can't use the query in the table (child component) since I use some items from that query in the parent component.
==============
Update 1:
While reading the documentation, I discovered the following:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/nesting#reactive-props
This is exactly what I need, but I'm using Livewire V2, which means I don't have this #React method.
==============
Update 2:
Sharing a bit of my code:
In the parent component, I retrieve the items like this:
$this->items = MyModel::where(filters...)->get();

As mentioned, I then pass these $items to the child component like this:
@livewire('admin.vendidos.contemplados.table.table-contemplados', ['items' => $items])

In the child component, I iterate over the items like this:
@foreach ($items as $index => $item)

As I mentioned before, this works quite well. However, the problem arises when I apply a filter in the parent component that changes the items. The items do not update in the child component.

Can't tell you why this happens, it should works, but i had exp to use Vue combenenstion and we have to use store  as it was reactive to the changes made from response from the api and we could use it as deep as we need, if you get what i'm saing

Okay, I understood what you meant, but I'm using the Blade engine and I'm not sure how to apply that in this case. Thank you for the contribuition!

Please post the related code, even if the description is detailed, something might be misrepresented. Look at how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example for details.
